# javascript templates best place to define

Tags: javascript

I want to use javascript tample, but unfortunately I can't include them in main layout/index.php file

The sample templates look like

```
<script type="text/x-tmpl" id="tmpl-demo">
    <h3>{%=o.title%}</h3>
    <p>Released under the
    <a href="{%=o.license.url%}">{%=o.license.name%}</a>.</p>
    <h4>Features</h4>
    <ul>
    {% for (var i=0; i<o.features.length; i++) { %}
        <li>{%=o.features[i]%}</li>
    {% } %}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Is there a way to declare such templates in javascript file? or  what can be the best way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you include them in layout/index.php?

Comment: As these are coming from 3rd party

Comment: And why can't you include templates from a 3rd party in your index.php? What are you planning to use to render the templates? You need to give us all the relevant information. Help us help you.